# How can I delete all but the newest 10 hidden folders in a directory

Tags: directory, delete

I backup .mozilla every (re)boot to a folder ~/nas-backups/mozilla but I only want to keep the most recent 10 folders alphabetically. The backups are stored with a date stamp e.g. .mozilla_2018_11_05_08:13

I want to delete all but the most recent 10 as part of a script but as they are hidden files I can not find a way to do it:

rm -R 'ls -t | tail -n +11' as it ignores hidden files/folders.

I have tried rm -R 'ls -ta | tail -n +11' but that doesn't work either.

If it could be expanded so it only kept the first backup of each day that would be a bonus.

May I request an explanation of any suggestions? Thanks.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not for names with spaces or newline characters.
- OK in your case where the names are like ".mozilla_2018_11_05_08:13 ".
- I presumed that there are no other files or folders in the mother folder ~/nas-backups/mozilla
- Tested it before posting:

  ```
  cd ~/nas-backups/mozilla
  total=$(ls -1A|wc -l); remove=$((total - 10)); rm -rv $(ls -1vA|head -n $remove)
  ```

explaination

```
total=$(ls -1A|wc -l) #total number of folders
remove=$((total - 10)) #total -10 so that 10 folders are not removed
rm -rv $(ls -1vA|head -n $remove) # removes total -10 from top(head)
# because older folders(by name) are first in ls -1vA (v switch lists the names 
# proper numeric order.
```

> ls --help
>
> -v                         natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Example:

```
:~/nas-backups/mozilla$ ls -1vA
.mozilla_2019_01_09_01:16
.mozilla_2019_01_09_18:12
.mozilla_2019_01_09_18:16
.mozilla_2019_01_09_19:16
.mozilla_2019_01_09_20:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_01:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_18:12
.mozilla_2019_01_10_18:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_19:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_20:16
.mozilla_2019_02_09_02:16
.mozilla_2019_02_09_18:12
.mozilla_2019_02_09_18:16
.mozilla_2019_02_09_19:16
.mozilla_2019_02_09_20:16
.mozilla_2019_03_09_03:16
.mozilla_2019_03_09_18:12
.mozilla_2019_03_09_18:16
.mozilla_2019_03_09_19:16
.mozilla_2019_03_09_20:16
.mozilla_2019_03_10_03:16
.mozilla_2019_03_10_18:12
.mozilla_2019_03_10_18:16
.mozilla_2019_03_10_19:16
.mozilla_2019_03_10_20:16
:~/nas-backups/mozilla$ total=$(ls -1A|wc -l); remove=$((total - 10)); rm -rv $(ls -1vA|head -n $remove)
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_09_01:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_09_18:12'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_09_18:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_09_19:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_09_20:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_10_01:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_10_18:12'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_10_18:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_10_19:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_01_10_20:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_02_09_02:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_02_09_18:12'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_02_09_18:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_02_09_19:16'
removed directory '.mozilla_2019_02_09_20:16'
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I put in total=$(ls -1A|wc -l)
If total > 11
as a test in case there are less than 10 - if there are everything is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls -tA|tail -n +11|xargs rm -R
```

This deletes all but the latest 10 files or folders (by file modification time) in a simple one-liner.

`ls -tA` lists all files including hidden ones, but without the `.` and `..` special files, sorted by modification time (newest first).

`tail -n +11` then takes only those files starting from the 11th entry (i.e. all but the 10 newest).

`xargs` just takes the output from tail and uses it as arguments to rm (executing rm once for each line from tail). Useful for commands that don't work with a simple pipe.

Comment: (Sorry for editing your reply - new to this)
Doesn't that do it on modification date date rather than alphabetically?

Comment: @David Yes it does it on file time stamp rather than date, which is what I assumed you wanted since your original post uses -t as well, and it does the same thing anyway. Anything else wouldn't be possible in a single line I'm afraid.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for replying. I will try to express myself more clearly in future.
I appreciate your explasnation - thanks,